# Query if key exists in an ElasticSearch hash

Tags: hash, elasticsearch

How do I check if my query terms are the keys in one of my fields? For example, here's a stored document:

```
{
  field1: "some value",
  field2: "some other value",
  field3: {
    something: [1,2],
    else: [2,3]
  }
}
```

The query "something" should return that document. The query "some value" should also return that document. Here's what I have so far:

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      query: {
        multi_match: {
          query: query,
          fields: ['field1', 'field2'],
          operator: 'and'
        }
      },
      filter: {
        or: [
          {
            exists: { field: "field3"}
          }
        ]
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want "some value" , in adjesent fashion , following should work fine -

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "field3"
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "field1": "some value"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "field2": "some value"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "something",
                "fields": [
                  "field1",
                  "field2"
                ],
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I took out the `match_phrase` part because I'm not passing in different query terms to different fields (i.e. the same terms are queried across all fields). Also this doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting the error: `No query registered for [exists]`. :(

Comment: The query "something" returns that document only because `match_phrase` is matching another string. Removing the nested bool does not return the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      filter: {
        or: [
          {
            query: {
              multi_match: {
                query: query,
                fields: ['field1', 'field2'],
                operator: "and"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            exists: { field: "field3.query" }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only caveat is that if `query` is a string with multiple terms (or an array), you'll have to create an `exists` filter for each term.